# What is interaction cross section of a photon and how to find it?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering-cross-section

I encountered this term while reading about photon interaction with metal electrons. Is this equal to the scattering cross section or is it different? How to find it mathematically?

> [image: proof the this quantity exists.]

Comment: Hi, can you please provide relevant references?

Comment: Yes.i will add a picture of a conversation with  a highly reputed physics stackexchange member.